# How to scale pie title in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, font-size

I'm trying to make title font dynamic, but on first load title is not centered enough:
[image]

but when I change screen size a little bit title looks like I want (I guess that the reason of it is that Y calculated before font-size is updated):

[image]

I need to fix it or find another solution to scale title. Title should become smaller when pie chart becomes smaller and title shouldn't be bigger than chart small radius.

https://jsfiddle.net/2kqn5agm/27/

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
            load: function () {
                this.title.attr({
                text: `<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;"><div>TEXT</div><div>label</div></div>`,
                });
            },
            render: function () {
            const plotInnerSize = Math.min(this.plotHeight, this.plotWidth) / 2;
    let fontSize = Math.round(0.15 * plotInnerSize);
    const y = this.plotTop + (this.plotHeight - fontSize) / 2 + fontSize / 3;
            this.title.css({fontSize: `${fontSize}px`}).attr({y});
            },
        },
  },
  title: {
        text: "",
        floating: true,
        useHTML: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            borderRadius: 0,
            slicedOffset: 0,
            size: "90%",
            innerSize: "60%",
        },
       
        series: {
            showInLegend: true,
        },
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false,
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false,
    },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33
    }, {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 24.03,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Comment: It looks like it is centered, but you have some whitespace appearing before the word 'TEXT'

Comment: @Kvasimodo  text-align: center; will work for you. ;)

Comment: @ArunKashyap where do you propose to set text-align: center;?

Comment: @Kvasimodo Let me know if the following solution meet your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wt78hxj/

Comment: @magdalena unfortunately, no. Center of the pie couldn't be set by static number (marginBottom: 20)

Comment: @Kvasimodo, I apologize for the misunderstanding. In general, in Highcharts, the recommended way to adjust an element's size relative to the chart size is by using responsive rules. You can find more information about responsive rules here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules ; https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/responsive